# Backbone Zombie View Solution

Tags: backbone.js

So, I have been working with Backbone for a while without any major issue. Though I have read a lot about the problem of Zombie Views and the memory leaks they generate. After some research I implemented a way of displaying the views that, hopefully, will prevent this issue. I have currently two apps working with this method and all seems to be going well but I would like to be sure that this method works.

All these functions are working on a main application object called "App" where the namespace for the app is defined and the application is initialized and then started.

Firs of all, my current solution works like this: when a Backbone router catches a url it instantiate all the models, collections and views that are needed to display that page but the router doesn't render the view. All it does it's append the view to a "contentView" array inside the App object and it delegates the rendering of the page also to App using the `App.setAndRenderContentViews` function.

On the App object I have two arrays containing all the views that are currently active. They are called "contentViews" and "appendedViews". On the first one are the main Views who may have some "appended Views" to display some models or collections. These last Views are stored in the appendedViews array.

Every time the router calls the `App.setAndRenderContentViews` functions, the applications run a series of methods to correctly close all the "oldViews" and then render the new Views. So, here is the code I'm using so far:

```
window.App =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}

  contentViews: []
  appendedViews: []

  setContentViews: (views) ->
    @closeViews() unless @contentViews == []
    @closeAppendedViews() unless @appendedViews == []
    for view in views
      @contentViews.push view
    return @contentViews

  closeViews: ->
    for oldView in @contentViews
      @closeView(oldView)
    @contentViews = []

  closeAppendedViews: ->
    for oldView in @appendedViews
      @closeView(oldView)
    @appendedViews = []

  closeView: (view) =>
    view.unbind()
    view.remove()
    view.model.off unless view.model == undefined
    view.collection.off unless view.collection == undefined

  renderContentView: (view) =>
    $('#content-layout').append(view.render().el)

  renderContentViews: (renderViews) ->
    for view in renderViews
      @renderContentView(view)
    return 1

  setAndRenderContentViews: (views, everybody = false) ->
    if everybody == false
      return Backbone.history.navigate('', trigger: true) unless @session.load().authenticated()
    renderViews = @setContentViews(views)
    @renderContentViews(renderViews)

  pushToAppendedViews: (view) ->
    @appendedViews.push view
```

I don't know if this is a good way to handle this problem. Also, maybe there is a better way of handling the Zombie Views. I hope one of you can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: I think this would work fine to prevent any memory leaks. My only issue is that I always prefer for the parent view to be responsible for taking care of all it's subviews. So if all of your views are being loaded/rendered by `window.App` then it makes sense to use your above strategy. But if there are parent views and then you add some sub-views, do you keep references of those sub-views in your `window.app.Views` array too? I think it violates the responsibility principle. The parent view should should be responsible for creating, rendering, closing and disposing off the views.

Comment: I only try to create sub-views inside my main views when appending a collection. For example if I want to show a Products list, then I create a ProductsIndex View, with a Products collection and another view call Product that render each model in the ProductsIndex view. Before I append this views I push them to the appendedViews array. Though I see what you mean. Maybe I can create a 'close' method inside a Base View and call it from the app when a View needs to be removed. What do you think?

Comment: yes. all parent views should be responsible for closing down the appended views. I think that would give it better structure and in case of memory leaks, easier to track where things went wrong. So basically every BaseView has a `close` method & an array of `appendedViews`. When you close, you call close of all `appendedViews` and then close itself.

Comment: Cool. I'll add at to my applications. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of Backbone you can be assured of cleaning up a view and all of its handlers/bindings simply by calling view.remove() and Backbone will take care of the rest for you (https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1277).

Comment: Yes, but or this to work all the events needs to be binded using the listenTo method. Thanks for the suggestion.